# Total users per period in mysql

Tags: mysql, count, case

I need to see in a judgment quarter registered users

eg:- quarter "Jan-Mar": 20

eg:- quarter "Apr-Jun": 30

```
id = id_ju1
registration date =date_regis
table = master

SELECT count(DISTINCT(id_ju1)), 
CASE 
WHEN month(date_regis) >=1 and month(date_regis) <=3 THEN 'Jan-Mar' 
WHEN  month(date_regis) >=4 and month(date_regis) <=6 THEN 'Apr-Jun' END 
FROM master
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use QUARTER function for this.

```
Dates that have a month of Jan-Mar would return 1.
Dates that have a month of Apr-Jun would return 2.
Dates that have a month of Jul-Sep would return 3.
Dates that have a month of Oct-Dec would return 4.
```

Refer:https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/quarter.php

```
SELECT QUARTER(date_regis) AS quarter, COUNT(DISTINCT(id_ju1)) AS idcount
FROM master 
GROUP BY QUARTER(date_regis)
ORDER BY QUARTER(date_regis)
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer, I run well, I have another question, also shows me quarter 0: As I remove the first element

Comment: Pls mark this as correct. If you have got the answer.

Comment: Thanks for response. why here you want zero?

Comment: For that you can use case statement with QUARTER()

Comment: o no, I mean that returns me the 5 periods the fifth is a 0, look http://liceotommys.edu.co/img.png,  as I can remove it

Answer (score 0):

Try something like bellow:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT(id_ju1))
FROM
(
SELECT ID_JUN1,
CASE 
WHEN month(date_regis) >=1 and month(date_regis) <=3 THEN 'jun-mar'
WHEN  month(date_regis) >=4 and month(date_regis) <=6 THEN 'mar-jun' END AS Quarter
FROM master
)
GROUP BY Quarter
```